# Using node to bring in a javascript page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a website that has about 400 lines of javascript code, on the front end. I want to put it on the back end so that when people visit the web page that uses the javascript, and click the submit button, only then does the website go to the server and use the necessary JS code, however with all the tutorials ive read and watched i cannot find anything specific to this, can anyone please help? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you simplify, or use diagram to show the flow? It's going to make it easier for others to understand and help you.

Comment: @razu yes, sorry. i have a page with a button, and when i click the button the onclick attribute runs a javascript function called work,                                                                                                 
 <div class = "col-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id = "submitDraftForm" onclick='work()'>Submit</button>                                                                 which runs a separate JS file, isntead of running the file directly, i want to retrieve the file from a server, as to prevent the code from being accessible on the front end.

Comment: You could load the JavaScript file using an Ajax request and then execute it using eval. But you won't be able to prevent users from reading your JavaScript code, you should never put anything that is secret (passwords, API tokens, etc.) in code that is executed on the client.